# Error Message: R script error. Error: unexpected symbol in: "# Epilog - Auto Generated # setwd" Execution halted

Tags: powerbi, rscript

Any help on this error message in R-script? Im running this in Power BI

Error Message: R script error. Error: unexpected symbol in: "# Epilog

- Auto Generated  # setwd" Execution halted

my r-script:

```
library(ggplot2)

dataset$`From`<-as.POSIXct(dataset$`From`,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
dataset$`To`<-as.POSIXct(dataset$`To`,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")

ggplot(dataset,aes(x=datetime_start, y=dataset$`Room`, color=(Person) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=From,xend=To,yend=dataset$`Room`),size=15) +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=10))) +
ggtitle("Room reservations for building X") + xlab("") + ylab("") + theme_bw()
```

[image: Image of error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with the code below.

```
library(ggplot2)

dataset$From<-as.POSIXct(dataset$From,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
dataset$To<-as.POSIXct(dataset$To,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")

ggplot(dataset, aes(From,Room,colour=Person))+
geom_segment(aes(x=From,xend=To,yend=dataset$Room),size=10)+
ggtitle("START/STOP")
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar Issue

```
library(ggplot2)

 ggplot( aes_(dataset$index,dataset$Qty)+
   geom_point()+
   geom_path()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).